# Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff Lindelöf scattered space. Is $\xi(X)$ a successor ordinal?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $K$ be a (Hausdorff) scattered topological space and for each ordinal $\alpha$ denote by $K^{(\alpha)}$ the $\alpha$th derivative of $K$ by the Cantor-Bendixson derivation (i.e., define transfinitely: $K^{(0)} = K$; for each ordinal $\alpha$, let $K^{(\alpha+1)}$ be the set of nonisolated points in $K^{(\alpha)}$ when $K^{(\alpha)}$ is equipped with the subspace topology); for $\alpha$ a limit ordinal, set $K^{(\alpha)}= \bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}K^{(\beta)}$).

Also, set $\xi(X) = inf\{ \alpha : X^{(\alpha)} = 0 \}$

I am trying to prove the following claim:

**Claim:** If $X$ is a Hausdorff Lindelöf scattered space, then, $\xi(X)$ is a successor ordinal.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\xi(X)$ is a limit ordinal. Then the set $\{ X \setminus X^{(\alpha)} : \alpha < \xi(X) \}$ is an open cover of $X$. $X$ is Lindelöf, so there is a countable subcover $\{ X \setminus X^{(\alpha_n)} : n \in \mathbb N, \alpha_n < \xi(X) \}$. We can also assume that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\alpha_n < \alpha_{n+1}$. Note that 
For each $n \in \mathbb N$, $X^{(\alpha_n)}$ is closed. Also, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $X^{(\alpha_{n+1})} \subset X^{(\alpha_n)}$ and $\bigcap X^{(\alpha_n)} = \emptyset$.  There exists no ordinal $\beta > 0$ such that $\xi(X^{(\alpha_n)}) \geq \beta$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$ because if there was, we woud get $\xi(\bigcap X^{(\alpha_n)}) \geq \beta$ which would imply $\bigcap X^{(\alpha_n)} \neq \emptyset$. So we can assume that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\xi(X^{(\alpha_n)}) > \xi(X^{(\alpha_{n+1})})$. So, the sequence $\xi(X^{(\alpha_n)})$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals. This implies that it has to be finite and that there is a finite $n \in \mathbb N$, such that $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (X \setminus X^{(\alpha_i)}) $. But this implies that $\xi(X) = \xi(X \setminus X^{(\alpha_n)}) < \xi(X)$ which is a contradiction. We conclude that $\xi(X)$ can only be a successor ordinal.

Comment: I don't see how you get that $\xi(X^{(\alpha_n)})_n$ is *strictly* decreasing.

Comment: Can it be non-decreasing with $X^{(\alpha_{n+1})} \subset X^{(\alpha_n)}$ and $\bigcap X^{(\alpha_n)} = \emptyset$?

Comment: If you look at my example $S$ below, then for all $n\in\omega$ you get $\xi(X^{(n)})=\omega$, while $X^{(\omega)}=\bigcap_n X^{(n)}=\emptyset$. The idea in general is that $1+\xi(X^{(1)})=\xi(X)$, and not $\xi(X^{(1)})+1=\xi(X)$. So in particular for every space $X$ with infinite Cantor-Bendixson rank we have $\xi(X^{(1)})=\xi(X)$.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim does not hold. In fact any subset $X$ of the Baire space with $\xi(X)$ equal to a limit countable ordinal would do as a counterexample. Here is a particular simple counterexample.

Consider the subspace $S$ of the Baire space $\omega^\omega$ defined by
 $$S=\{k^{\smallfrown} x \mid k\in\omega \text{ and $x\in 2^\omega$ with $\{i\mid x(i)=1\}\leq k$}\}$$
You can verify that $S$ is closed.

Since the Baire space is second countable (*i.e.* admits a countable basis of open sets), $S$ is second countable too. Since a second countable space is Lindelöf, $S$ is Lindelöf.

Now you can check that for all $n\in\omega$
$$S^{(n)}=\{k^{\smallfrown}x\mid n\leq k\text{ and $x\in 2^\omega$ with $\{i\mid x(i)=1\}\leq k-n$}\}.$$
It follows that $S^{(\omega)}=\emptyset$ and so $\xi(S)=\omega$.